# Google Cloud platform - Migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

I have a question about the Google Cloud Platform migration.

We currently have one GCP project which is  dedicated for one customer. We would like to move this project (and all components attached to it) to a new/different Google project.

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: Do you mean to move the billing/organization of the project?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. No it's more if we can move a project to an another root organisation.

Comment: If it's inside an organization it should be possible to transfer the rights to another one. The same way you can do with the billing.

Comment: hi @night-goldno it's outside the current organisation

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing

Answer (score 1):

Here [1] you can see the official procedure to follow in case you would like to migrate a project from an Organization or even a project from a NO-Organization project(Handling special cases).

1. Create a migration plan
2. Assign permissions
3. Configure organization policies
4. Perform the migration

[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration